# Symfony 6: Doctrine Retains Old Database Values After Switching – How to Disable Caching?

Tags: ajax, sqlite, symfony, caching, doctrine

I have set up a configuration in my Symfony 6 application that uses multiple SQLite databases. **To switch between databases, I change the symbolic link of the file** , which works well except in the first minute after the change.

When I switch databases via an AJAX request, the old values are retained for about a minute, and the new values are not retrieved. However, if I reload the page manualy, the correct values are displayed.

I have tried several approaches to solve this issue, including cache deletion, modifying Doctrine configuration parameters, and forcibly closing the connection in the repository, but nothing has resolved the problem.

**It seems that Doctrine is retaining data or the SQLite file in memory. Is there a way to instruct Doctrine not to cache anything?**

I have attempted several approaches to address the issue:

**Cache Deletion**: Initially, I tried deleting the cache to ensure that any cached data related to the previous database would be cleared. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.

**Doctrine Configuration Modification**: I experimented with modifying Doctrine configuration parameters, including setting the memory parameter to false and adjusting the lifetime parameter to 0. However, these changes did not have the desired effect.

**Forced Connection Closure**: In an attempt to force the closure of the connection after a query in the repository, I implemented code to explicitly close the connection. Despite this, the problem persisted.

**Page Reload**: As a workaround, I observed that reloading the entire page resolved the issue. This led me to suspect that Doctrine might be caching data or the SQLite file.

My expectation was that these steps would ensure the immediate and accurate switch to the new database without retaining any old values. However, the problem persists within the first minute after switching databases via AJAX, indicating that Doctrine might be holding onto cached data.

Some files details:

**Doctrine configuration**

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            sqlite:
                url: '%env(resolve:SQLITE_DATABASE_URL)%'
                memory: false
        default_connection: default
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    mysql:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/mysql'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\mysql'
                        alias: mysql
            sqlite:
                connection: sqlite
                second_level_cache:
                    enabled: false
                    region_lifetime: 0
                mappings:
                    sqlite:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/sqlite'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\sqlite'
                        alias: sqlite
```

**How i change the link**

```php
if (is_link($sqlitePath)){
    unlink($sqlitePath);
  }
        
  if (symlink($pathDB,$sqlitePath)) {
    $this->updateCurrentProject($project);
    return $project;
  }
```

**How i clear the manager**

```php
class DeviceRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private ManagerRegistry $registry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($registry, Device::class);

    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        $data = parent::findAll();
        $this->registry->getManager('sqlite')->clear();
        return $data;
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.